# Can I answer the azan after some time?

Tags: ramadan

Let's say while the azan was being sounded,  I didn't respond to it - either because of forgetfulness, sleep or being in a place where I couldn't hear the azan but when seeing the time realising that the azan must have been announced.

So can I answrr the azan later ?

Comment: No. It's only applicable when the adhan is happening, not afterward.

Comment: The hadith makes clear that you should listen and repeat at once not later.